# Between these bonds, how to find out which is one pricey (Higher valuation) and cheap (Lower valuation)?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, valuation

Trying to understand, how to find out which of these bonds are cheap and which are expensive?

The current spot rate is 8.167%. How do I go about finding the cheap vs expensive bonds especially when YTM is same?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 3 bonds form a triangle - given the price of two of them, you can calculate the third.  So your calc is correct, but all you can conclude is that the coupon bond is cheap relative to the zero coupon bonds.

Comment: Thanks @dm63. I just want to confirm, my calculations do make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

Using discount factors, the 8% coupon bond should be trading at
( 8 * .96154) + ( 108 * .85734) = $100.285

Since it is trading only at $100, the coupon paying bond is cheaper and zero coupon bonds are trading at higher premium.